# Custom adapter returning wrong row Textview Text

Tags: android

I am implementing a custom adapter for listview. In which i have some textview and one checkbox.for checkbox i have implemented `setOnCheckedChangeListener`.But the problem is when i check a checkbox i am trying to get that row textview text. but it returning last row textview text.

**Code**

```
  public class CustomStoreAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements Filterable {

        ItemFilter mFilter;
        int price;
        private int lastPosition = -1;
        ViewHolder mHolder;

        ArrayList<String> favHotel;
        private static SparseBooleanArray positionArray=new SparseBooleanArray();
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
        public static ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> finalHashList;
        public static ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> tempName;
        public static ArrayList<Integer> selectedIds = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        Context context;
        String flag;
        String favId;
        ArrayList<String> htlId;
        String [] favArr;

        public CustomStoreAdapter(String flag, Context context, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> finalHashList, String favId) {
            System.out.println("custom size>>"+finalHashList.size());
            this.context = context;

          CustomStoreAdapter.finalHashList =finalHashList;
            for (int i=0;i<finalHashList.size();i++) {
                htlId.add(finalHashList.get(i).get("id"));
            }
            tempName=finalHashList;
            selectedIds=new ArrayList<>();
            this.flag=flag;
            this.favId=favId;
            if (!favId.equals(""))
            {
                favId=favId.substring(6,favId.length());
                //Log.e("substring favId",favId);
               favArr=favId.split(",");
            }
            Log.e("flag is>>>",flag);

        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return finalHashList.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return finalHashList.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }
        public static void append( ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> finalHashList1) {


        }

        public static StringBuilder getCheckedItems() {


            StringBuilder mTempArry = new StringBuilder();

            mTempArry.append("htlid=");


            for(int i=0;i<finalHashList.size();i++) {


                if(positionArray.get(i)) {

                   mTempArry.append(finalHashList.get(i).get("id"));
                    mTempArry.append(",");

                }

            }



            return mTempArry;


        }

        @Override
        public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            favHotel=new ArrayList<>();
            View v = convertView;
            sharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences("hotelDekho", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

            if(finalHashList.size() > position) {

                LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                TypefaceUtil.overrideFont(context.getApplicationContext(), "SERIF", "fonts/splash-font.ttf");
                if (v == null) {
                    v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.serch_result_page, parent, false);
                    mHolder = new ViewHolder();

                    mHolder.txtId=(TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.txtId);
                     mHolder.txthotelRating = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.txtRating);
                    mHolder.txthotelName = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.Hotel_name);
                    mHolder.txtFavorite=(CheckBox) v.findViewById(R.id.imgFavorite);
                    mHolder.txthotelLocation = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.Hotel_location);
                    mHolder.txthotelPrice = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.price);
                    mHolder.txthotelPrice2 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.price2);
                    mHolder.txthotelIconPlace = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.locIcon);
                    mHolder.txtLock = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.txtLock);
                    mHolder.txthotelIconR1 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.txtR1);
                    mHolder.txthotelIconR2 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.txtR2);
                    mHolder.rhotelRating = (CustomRatingBar) v.findViewById(R.id.ratingBar1);
                    mHolder.lnrPrice=(LinearLayout)v.findViewById(R.id.lnrPrice);
                    mHolder.imgHotel = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.hotel_image);
                    mHolder.lnrRating=(LinearLayout)v.findViewById(R.id.lnrRating);
                    mHolder.lnrSignHotelList=(LinearLayout)v.findViewById(R.id.lnrSignHotelList);
                    mHolder.txthotelIconPlace.setTypeface(FontManager.getTypeface(context, FontManager.FONTAWESOME));

                    mHolder.txthotelIconR1.setTypeface(FontManager.getTypeface(context, FontManager.FONTAWESOME));
                    mHolder. txthotelIconR2.setTypeface(FontManager.getTypeface(context, FontManager.FONTAWESOME));

                    mHolder.txtLock.setTypeface(FontManager.getTypeface(context, FontManager.FONTAWESOME));
                    mHolder.txtFavorite.setTag(position);

                    v.setTag(mHolder);
                }else

                {
                    mHolder = (ViewHolder) v.getTag();
                    mHolder.txtFavorite.setOnCheckedChangeListener(null);
                }


                Animation animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context, (position > lastPosition) ? R.anim.up_from_bottom : R.anim.down_from_top);
               v.startAnimation(animation);
                lastPosition = position;

                    mHolder.txtId.setText(finalHashList.get(position).get("id"));
                    mHolder.txthotelName.setText(finalHashList.get(position).get("name"));
                    mHolder.txthotelLocation.setText(finalHashList.get(position).get("location"));
                    mHolder.txthotelRating.setText(finalHashList.get(position).get("rating") + "/5");
               // mHolder.txtFavorite.setChecked(positionArray.get(position));

                mHolder.txtFavorite.setChecked(positionArray.get(position));
                for (int i=0;i<favArr.length;i++)
                {
                    if(favArr[i].equals(finalHashList.get(position).get("id")))
                    {
                        mHolder.txtFavorite.setChecked(true);
                    }
                }
                mHolder.txtFavorite.setOnCheckedChangeListener(mCheckedChangeListener);
                if (!flag.equals("favHtl")) {
                    mHolder.lnrPrice.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    Float price1 = Float.parseFloat(finalHashList.get(position).get("price"));
                    mHolder.txthotelPrice2.setText(String.valueOf(Math.round(price1)));

                    if (SearchHotelResults.flag.equals("offer")) {
                        price = Math.round(price1 + price1);
                    } else
                        price = Math.round(price1 + ((price1 * 20) / 100));
                    mHolder.txthotelPrice.setText(String.valueOf(price));
                    mHolder.txthotelPrice.setPaintFlags(mHolder.txthotelPrice.getPaintFlags() | Paint.STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG);
                }
                mHolder.rhotelRating.refreshDrawableState();
                if (!sharedPreferences.getString("email","").equals(""))
                {
                    mHolder.lnrSignHotelList.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }

                mHolder.rhotelRating.setScore(Float.parseFloat(finalHashList.get(position).get("star")));


                    if (finalHashList.get(position).get("img").startsWith("hoteldekho")) {
                        loadImagePicaso( mHolder.imgHotel, Config.storeImagePath + finalHashList.get(position).get("img"));
                    } else {
                        loadImagePicaso( mHolder.imgHotel, finalHashList.get(position).get("img"));
                    }



                }
            return v;

            }
        CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener mCheckedChangeListener = new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {




            @Override


            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {


                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                Animation zoomOutAnimation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(), R.anim.bounce);
                buttonView.startAnimation(zoomOutAnimation);
                positionArray.put(htlId.indexOf(mHolder.txtFavorite.getText().toString()), isChecked);
                Log.e("array is>>",getCheckedItems().toString()+">>>>"+ finalHashList.indexOf(mHolder.txtId.getText().toString()));
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();

                editor.putString("favHotelId", getCheckedItems().toString());
                editor.apply();

            }


        };

 private class ViewHolder {
        private TextView txtId;
        private TextView txthotelRating;
        private TextView txthotelName;
        private TextView txthotelLocation;
        private TextView txthotelPrice;
        private TextView txthotelPrice2;
        private TextView txthotelIconPlace;
        private  TextView txtLock;
        private CheckBox txtFavorite;
        LinearLayout lnrPrice;
        private TextView txthotelIconR1;
        private TextView txthotelIconR2;
        private TextView txthotelIconArrow;
        private CustomRatingBar rhotelRating;
        private ImageView imgHotel;
        private Button btnSubmit;
        private LinearLayout lnrRating;
        private LinearLayout lnrSignHotelList;
    }


    }
```

Please help me to how to get same row textview text on checkbox click

Comment: you can get the parent of checkbox and find the relevant textview.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Problem:**

Currently you're storing your `ViewHolder` in a class level field, which is being set in `getView()`, its going to be set to the latest ViewHolder every time ListView is calling `getView()` and there's absolutely no guarantee in the order of the position the `getView()` is called for. Its going to get random `ViewHolder` references, creating problems for you to track position So a class level `ViewHolder` isn't good solution.

**Solution:**

You need to keep track of position related to every check box. Tag the position to checkbox and get it in the listener as follow:

```
mHolder.txtFavorite.setOnCheckedChangeListener(mCheckedChangeListener);
mHolder.txtFavorite.setTag(position+""); //tag position as String object
```

Now you can get this position in your listener:

```
public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
    //Since we set position in form of String, we need to convert String to int
    int position = Integer.parseInt(buttonView.getTag());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You save position of mHolder.txtFavorite to tag, so you should just read the right position from tag, not from text

```
positionArray.put(htlId.indexOf(mHolder.txtFavorite.getTag()), isChecked);
```